# Many-to-Many relation in EF Api Fluent error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I try to make a Many-To-Many relation with the Fluent API on .Net Core, I get the error with `add-migration`:

`The property or navigation 'MembreId' cannot be added to the entity type 'Gracci.Models.Achat' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'Gracci.Models.Achat'.`

Model `Achat` contains the user's purchases

```cs
    public class Achat
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int MembreId { get; set; }
        public Membre Membre { get; set; }
        public int ProduitId { get; set; }
        public Produit Produit { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Unite { get; set; }
    }
```

Model `Membre` contains member data

```cs
public class Membre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(35)]
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(35)]
        public string Prenom { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string MotDePasse { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsResponsable { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(0.0)]
        public float Solde { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Achat> Achats { get; set; }

    }
```

Model `Produit` contains the products for sale

```cs
public class Produit
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public float Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Stock { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool? isActif { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Achat> Achats { get; set; }
    }
```

The code for my relations between `Member` - `Purchase` - `Product` in `GracciDbContext`. I did add `DbSet<Membre>`,`DbSet<Achat>` and `DbSet<Produit>`

```cs
            /* FLUENT API ACHAT */
            modelBuilder.Entity<Achat>()
                .Property(s => s.Unite)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValue(1);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Achat>()
                .Property(s => s.Date)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");


            /* FLUENT API ACHAT - PRODUIT/MEMBRE MANY-TO-MANY */
            modelBuilder.Entity<Achat>().HasKey(p => new { p.MembreId, p.ProduitId});*/

           modelBuilder.Entity<Achat>()
                .HasOne<Produit>(achat => achat.Produit)
                .WithMany(prod => prod.Achats)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.ProduitId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Achat>()
                .HasOne<Membre>(achat => achat.Membre)
                .WithMany(memb => memb.Achats)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.MembreId);
```

I had used Fluent Api for constraints, but I converted that to an annotation...

Comment: I was able to migrate with your model.
did you use ef core?

Comment: @user3104267 Nuget packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` have been installed. And in my code, i'm using `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deleted the migrations present in the corresponding folder. And the add-migration worked.